# How I can change this deprecated code document.write for improve pagespeed

Tags: javascript

I would like to improve a code that I have in the sidebar of wordpress, where what I want is that every time people enter randomly loads an image. At the moment with the code I have shown below it works, but when I put my page in google speed it says this:

Avoid use: **document.write()**

```js
link = new Array();
link[0] = '<a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img src="" width="300" height="408"/></a>';
link[1] = '<a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img src="" width="300" height="408"/></a>';
link[2] = '<a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img src="" width="300" height="408"/></a>';
link[3] = '<a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener nofollow"><img src="" width="300" height="408"/></a>';
random = Math.random() * (link.length);
random = Math.floor(random);
document.write(link[random]);
```

```html
<div id="bloquewidget"></div>
```

Comment: Use [DOM Manipulation methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) instead.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't look to be any need for the array or randomness since the link HTMLs are all the same. Create an `<a>` with `createElement`, then use a CSS selector to insert it into the document at the appropriate point. You'll need some way to uniquely identify this `<div>` - use a class if it already has one, or give the div a class, such as `link-container`:

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.target = '_blank';
a.rel = 'noopener nofollow';
// do you want to add a non-empty src to the a here?
const img = a.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
img.width = 300;
img.height = 408;
// do you want to add a non-empty src to the image here?

// insert <a> at the bottom of this div:
document.querySelector('.link-container').appendChild(a);
```

Comment: I must add this bellow the code I wrote before or what? sorry but I am noob to java coding...

Comment: Replace your entire `<script>` with the code in my answer. And Java is extremely different from JavaScript.

Comment: You're using an ID, not a class. To select an element with an ID, put `#` before the selector, not `.` You also need to assign to the `href` property of the `a`, and to the `src` property of the `img`. `a.href =` and `img.src =`

Comment: wow now its working, where I can add more images and more URL?

Comment: What do you mean, add more images?

Comment: In my first code I haved 4 diferent images of games and that links go to diferents URL, so when somebody enter to my website one time can see the image 1 for example and if he reload the browser can appear another image random. So the idea if have mayebe 8 diferents images and each image go to one diferent URL.

Comment: Please make sure to include the code you're *actually using* in questions when you post them - the current code in your question does not show such a thing. If you want random paired images and links, use an array `[{ link: 'https://bstk.me/lzZOLJOOk', src: 'https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/android/west-game.jpg' }]` etc, then choose a random item from the array, and assign the random item's properties to the `href` and `src` respectively

Comment: I put the code I use on my website and it works fine generating a random image every time people enter, the only thing is that when I pass it through this website for check the page speed https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ it recomend me that I have to change the document.write because it is obsolete. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The code in your question does not contain different HTML markups in the array, but it sounds like the site you're actually using does use different HTML markups. Remember to post your code *verbatim* when asking questions to get useful answers so that silly back-and-forth in comments like these isn't necessary.

Comment: Like I said, if you want to randomize things, use an array `[{ link: 'https://bstk.me/lzZOLJOOk', src: 'https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/android/west-game.jpg' }]` etc, then choose a random item from the array, and assign the random item's properties to the href and src respectively

Comment: is it too much to ask for an example with 2 images and 2 links of the all code to copy and paste please?

Comment: I explained how to do it in two comments already. Take a random item from the array, like your original code is doing. Say you put it into a variable `randomObj`. Then assign the properties of the object to the image and anchor. `a.href = randomObj.link;` and `img.src = randomObj.src`

Comment: ok thanks a lot, I'm going to try to do it on my own to see if I have luck, I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

the

```
document.write(link[random]);
```

part can be replaced with:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + link[random];
```

It is also worth looking into [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for creating DOM objects like anchors.

Comment: When I chante this code:the widget of worpress dissapear  `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + link[random];` thanks for you quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well I found another solution to my problem I leave the code here in case anyone else needs to put in a wordpress a widget with images that are randomly generated with their own link and not using the deprecated code document.write

```
<div id="bloquewidget">
<a id="a" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"><img id="image" /></a>
```

```js
<script type='text/javascript'> 
var images = 
[
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"your URL image here", Href:"your URL here" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"your URL image here", Href:"your URL here" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"your URL image here", Href:"your URL here" },
    imageUrlPair = { ImgSrc:"your URL image here", Href:"your URL here" },
]

function randImg() {
var size = images.length;
var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random());
var randomItem = images[x];
document.getElementById('image').src = randomItem.ImgSrc;
document.getElementById('a').href = randomItem.Href;
document.getElementById("image").height = "408";
document.getElementById("image").width = "300";

}

randImg();
</script>
```